# How do I know if a review suspension/ban is automatic or manual?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage, review-suspension

I just found out I got banned from reviewing for 16 days for [triage/25566143](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25566143) (not an audit).

After carefully reading the question again I came to the conclusion I should have voted for `Unsalvageable` because the poster did not provide any example JSON code and did not even ask a question! It looks more like the poster is seeking for some debugging help or code writing service.

**Is this an automatic or a manual ban?**

To me it appears to be like an automatic ban because I can't see a moderator's username and diamond (♦) icon in the ban message. Is this correct? And if yes, how does automated suspensions work?

Comment: *"I can't see a moderator icon"* What do you mean by "a moderator icon"? What icon would you expect to see? The name of the individual moderator who issues a ban is never shown in the user interface.

Comment: @CodyGray I mean this icon: ♦. Isn't such an icon shown in the ban message when you got manually banned?

Comment: No. The diamond icon is only shown after a user name, and no user name appears for ban messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Is it an Automated or Manual Review Ban?

If it was an automated review ban (for failing several review audits), 
the **review ban message** found on [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) will begin with: "*You have made too many incorrect reviews*"

In your case, a moderator wanted to highlight your action(s) on specific review(s) to you.

---

#### Review Suspension Appeals

If you want to discuss the review or appeal the ban, then feel free to [ask a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion+review+review-suspension) on Meta with the tag [review-suspension](/questions/tagged/review-suspension).

In the question, you should include:

- the suspension message (including links to the reviews)
- screenshots of the review if the post is currently deleted (for <10k rep users)
- an explanation of why you think the suspension is incorrect and/or should be lifted

#### A very good example of how to submit a suspension appeal:

- [Reflection on temporary ban from Review Queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394684/reflection-on-temporary-ban-from-review-queue)

---

#### Asking for general help/advice about reviews

Feel free to drop by the [**Reviews room**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews) in chat to ask about the review queues in general, a specific review, or review suspensions.