# Reflection on temporary ban from Review Queue

Tags: discussion, status-completed, triage, review-suspension

My reviewing privileges were recently suspended because [I marked a post as *Requires Editing*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25616785) which was later closed as being *Off Topic*.

I understand from reading [the post linked from the suspension notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389148/getting-banned-from-review-although-my-co-reviewers-agree-with-me) that this is because subsequent reviewers found that no amount of editing could salvage the post. Notably, I am assuming that [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708245/reading-site-without-open-graph) violated [the following guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Positively, I had recognized that concern and even considered flagging it myself. Negatively, not only did I neglect to do so but, worse, instead did the follow:

1. Marked the post as *Requires Editing*,
2. Immediately [submitted an edit myself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25618316), and
3. Provided [a comment offering direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708245/reading-site-without-open-graph) to the OP.

I did this because the OP is a new(er) contributor, and seemed stuck due to not knowing the appropriate keywords to search by. At the time, I assumed a softer touch would be preferred here.

That said, on hindsight, the lessons I'm taking away from this are:

1. As a reviewer in the *Triage Queue*, it wasn't my role to then submit an edit;
2. While my edit may have helped clarify the question, it did nothing to address the fundamental issue; and
3. We need to uphold the site's policies, and *especially* for new users to help them learn the ropes.

Is this a correct read of the situation? I want to make sure that I don't make this mistake again.

If I'm correctly reading the situation, would you consider lifting my temporary ban? Alternatively, if I'm taking the wrong lessons away here, can you clarify what I did wrong so I can avoid doing so in the future?

Comment: People, take note, this is how review ban appeals should be written.

Comment: Your logic looks sound to me

Comment: Thank you much for lifting my ban; I really appreciate it. We’re quarantined here in Seattle, and reviewing Stack Overflow posts is a welcome distraction right now! I’ll be more careful and diligent in the future.

Answer (score 16):

I've noticed that you've had your ban lifted, but I'd like to make an important point:

- *never* select "Requires Editing" in Triage unless the post is off-topic but can be edited to become on-topic.

For example, a question asking for a tutorial on how to do something can instead be edited into asking how to do something (maybe).

If you think that a post "Requires Editing", your best bet is to skip it.

Comment: That’s a really useful clarification; thank you. I’ll definitely proceed with more care.